# Relationship with non primary key field

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my project I need the following tables:

**users**

- *id:integer* (primary key, auto increment)
- *username:string*
- *consumerId:string*

**subscriptions**

- *id:integer* (primary key, auto increment)
- *plan:string*
- *consumerId:string*

The `users` table contains information of users in the application. However, to handle subscriptions to a premium plan in my project I'm using an external API that gives me a `consumerId` for each of my premium users.
Thus I store this `consumerId` in the `users` table to make it correspond to a user.

Now, I would like to manage a list of `subscriptions` (second table).
For this list it's easier for me to use `consumerId` (because the API gives me this ID and I would like to avoid an extra query to retrieve the user ID for this `consumerId`). Also, each `user` can have several `subscriptions`. So I need to have an ID for the `subscription`, a `plan` and the `consumerId` of the user who is subscribing.

Now I would like to create a relationship between the `users` table and the `subscriptions` table with the `consumerId` as the key. One `user` can have several `subscriptions`.

How can I describe it in term of migration script and schema with `Ecto`?

Comment: _Sidenote_: it’s always a bad idea to skimp on _write_ queries. One should better use a primary `id` there. Writing to the database is rare, while tomorrow you’ll find yourself constructing redundant queries and guards to handle corner cases.

Comment: So, you would make the extra query to retrieve the *id* of the user and use that id as the relationship key instead of the *consumerId*?

Comment: Yes, I would. And my future me will praise me for that. Unless you are creating thousands of subscriptions per a second, it’s safe.